# App built with capacitor, Deeplink opens in browser rather than opening the app in Android 12 device

Tags: android, deep-linking, capacitor

I am trying to use deep linking in my app, which is built using Capacitor and runs on Android 12 devices. The deep linking works fine in a native Android app, but it is not working in the Capacitor build. I have used the same intent filters in both the Capacitor project and the native Android project, but the deep linking still doesn't work in the Capacitor build.

Intent filter used added in the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
     <data android:scheme="https" android:host="www.mysite.com" />
</intent-filter>
```

Same intent used for native sample and capacitor sample app. It worked fine with native one. Opened in browser for app build with capacitor. Issue is occuring only in Android 12 + devices only.

Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions for what might be causing the deep linking to fail in the Capacitor build, but not in the native Android app? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: On Android 12 and higher, clicking a `web link` (that is not an `Android App Link`) always shows content in a web browser. You use `Android App Link`, did you create a [site association file](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/guides/deep-links#android-configuration)?

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure what you mean by "Capacitor build".

But in my case I had to make sure the app is signed with the key who's fingerprint I used in the assetlinks.json

A debug build (maybe what you mean by capacitor build?) will not automatically verify the links but will work if you manually select the links in the app settings on the installed device.